# How to keep my branch clean without deleting others work?

Tags: git

I recently joined a small project with other 2 people.

we have a git repository with a bunch of stuff they have been working on, and I am working only on a small feature with 4 files.

My problem is this: in our repository we have stuff I wanted to keep on my pc and maybe change them little bit (e.g. .idea dir is on the repository for some reason) but I didn't wanted it to affect others so I used:

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```

(and on some other directories and files).

But, if I try to merge my branch with the master's, all of the files I removed will be deleted from the repository.

How can I exclude all of the files from the branch and still won't delete them on the masters when merging?

I tried using .gitignore after the commands but it still wasn't very helpful.

Comment: other than gitignore, you may change the file in .git/info/exclude to state files that are ignored on your machine. This is a local setting, it won't be shared anywhere. Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

Try to merge your branch with the `--no-commit` option and remove after them the staged file and ignore the changes from this file.

As example, to ignore all changes on the *exampleFile.txt* by merging, then try the following:

This creates actually a normal merge but without a merge-commit:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit <merge-branch>
```

Remove the file from stage and make the file unstaged:

```
git reset HEAD exampleFile.txt
```

Revert the file back to the state where it was before the changes:

```
git checkout -- exampleFile.txt
```

Make the commit with the reverted *exampleFile.txt*:

```
git commit -m "merged to master-branch"
```

Synch local branch with remote branch:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your workflow...

1. If there is a valid reason to change this files, just create a new commit (maybe on a new branch) and share these changes with your team
2. If you need to change these files temporally (e.g. to test/debug something), just edit     them but do not stage/commit the changes (never use blind `git add -A`)
3. If these files are just local or temporally files (e.g. the config of your IDE). Do not keep track of them by git (remove them and add to .gitignore).